# Why do arrays behave this way when I add named properties?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I did following experiment in browsers console

1. I created a new `Array`.
2. Added `"foo"` to the `Array` as named index `"name"`.
3. Added `"bar"` to the `Array` using `push` method.

4 & 5 are tests on the  `Array`

```
1. var myArray = [];            // undefined
2. myArray["name"] = "foo";     // "foo"
3. myArray.push("bar");         // 1

4. myArray.join(", ");          // "bar"
5. myArray["name"];             // "foo"
```

My questions (what I didn't understand)

- `.push()` returns `1` which is the length of the `Array`, but it must be 2 as the `Array` has two values "foo" & "bar"
- Test 4 shows that the `Array` has only one value `"bar"` but test 5 oppose it showing that it also has a value `"foo"`.
- Why doesn't  `Array` methods (`push`, `join` etc) works on key/value pairs ?
- Then how does associative `Array` works and how we can handle it(methods, properties etc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> .push() returns 1 which is the length of the Array, but it must be 2 as the Array has
>   two values "foo" & "bar"

No, because arrays in JavaScript are not associative data structures (even though you *can* attach arbitrary properties to them). The only items that count as "array contents" are those whose property names satisfy [certain conditions](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4).

You should also be aware that [`length`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.5.2) may also report a number greater than what you expect if the array has "holes". For example:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(a.join(" "), a.length); // "1 2 3", 3
delete a[1];
console.log(a.join(" "), a.length); // "1  3", still 3!
```

> Test 4 shows that the Array has only one value "bar" but test 5 oppose it showing that it also has a value "bar".

That's irrelevant. The array also has many other properties, but [`join`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.5) will only touch those mentioned earlier.

> Why doesn't Array methods (push, join etc) works on key/value pairs ?

Because that's what the spec says.

> Then how does associative Array works and how we can handle it(methods, properties etc).

Use a plain object instead of an array if you want string keys.

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript doesn't really have associative arrays. Being able to do `myArray["foo"] = "bar"` is a side effect of arrays simply being objects, and objects having properties.

Only numeric properties count as elements of the array. If you do `myArray["foo"] = "bar"` you are **not** adding an element to the array, you're simply adding a property to the object. That's different to doing `myArray[0] = "bar"` which *is* adding an element, and will accordingly update the `length` property of the array object.

Comment: Js have associative arrays : a js Object *is* an associative array.

Comment: @GameAlchemist Not in the way the OP is describing. JavaScript has no type that will auto-count and iterate all of its keys.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski `Object.keys()` does that.

Comment: Yes i was about to say like @Pavlo. for (var p in) or Object, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor, Object.getOwnPropertyNames, Object.Keys are various ways to get the keys.

Comment: @Pavlo Yes. But, that is not built-in to the instance as a property or method (i.e. `length`). It's a "*static*" method of the `Object` constructor. So, the logic can be accomplished, but not by a particular type.

Comment: @Jonathan Lonowski : I think your latest answer might be called dammage control. :-)

Comment: @GameAlchemist It's a rebuttal, sure. But, I said "*as the OP is describing*." The OP wants the logic to be in the `Array` type, which it isn't. Neither is it built in to `Object` (instances).

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript you cannot address array elements with a string, only integers. So,

```
1. var myArray = [];            // undefined
2. myArray["name"] = "foo";     // "foo"
3. myArray.push("bar");
```

`myArray` will only contain "bar" since it ignores `myArray["name"] = "foo";` which is why you get length 1.

Comment: Actually, you can access an element using string as a key if the string can be casted to a number, try `myArray["0"]`.

Comment: @pavlo and if you do, a kitten will die somewhere. Don't do it! Save the kitteh =)

Answer (score 0):

Just like functions, Arrays are objects.  But there are many Array prototype functions which purposefully do not access the properties of object.  There is no 'associative array' in JavaScript, other than object and arrays depending on the function or code can behave or be leveraged in the same way you would use an associative array.  You will encounter the same confusion in for loops when iterating over object key/pairs vs array values.  In general though they are quite effective, there is a good book called Java Script the good parts.  Which also then highlights the features or 'bad parts' to avoid or are dangerous.  Googling about the sharp edges of objects and arrays in Javascript yields some good reads.  They are not complex, but you do have to understand the more subtle ways Java is not like JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in Javascript are not meant to be associative - when you add a property via a key you're actually adding it to the array object, not to the array itself.

If you want a key:value pair, [use an Object](http://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/)