# How to convert array strings into key value pair in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an array

```
arr = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

I want to convert it into

```
arr = ['a': false, 'b':false, 'c':false]
```

So I can access value like this
`arr['a']` and get result `false`.

Comment: what did you try ?

Comment: `Object.fromEntries(arr.map(m => [m, false]))`

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve ?

Answer (score 3):

You *can* late bind properties on to a javascript `Array`, but you [probably](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20270345/why-do-arrays-behave-this-way-when-i-add-named-properties) [shouldn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27895365/is-it-good-practice-to-add-properties-on-array-in-javascript)! Instead turn it to an object by using `reduce`:

```js
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c' ];
var obj = arr.reduce( (acc,curr) => {
   acc[curr] = false;
   return acc;
},{});

console.log(obj["a"])
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple object map should be fine here

```
let arr=['a', 'b', 'c' ];
let object = Object.fromEntries(arr.map(
    function newPairs(m){
        return [m, false];
    }
));

console.log("Print array " + JSON.stringify(arr));
console.log("Print object " + JSON.stringify(object));
```